# Passing Laravel .env variable to Dockerfile

Tags: laravel, docker, dockerfile

I have code in my Dockerfile that install NewRelic php client

```
RUN \
  curl -L https://download.newrelic.com/php_agent/release/newrelic-php5-8.3.0.226-linux.tar.gz | tar -C /tmp -zx && \
    NR_INSTALL_USE_CP_NOT_LN=1 NR_INSTALL_SILENT=1 /tmp/newrelic-php5-*/newrelic-install install && \
      rm -rf /tmp/newrelic-php5-* /tmp/nrinstall* && \
        sed -i -e 's/"REPLACE_WITH_REAL_KEY"/"${MY_NEWRELIC_KEY}"/' \
     -e 's/newrelic.appname = "PHP Application"/newrelic.appname = "MyApp"/' \
         /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/newrelic.ini
```

How to pass variable MY_NEWRELIC_KEY that defined in Laravel .env file to DockerFile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define [ARG](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg) and [ENV](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env) values. 
`ARG` are also known as `build-time` variables. They are only available from the moment they are 'announced' in the `Dockerfile` with an `ARG` instruction up to the moment when the image is built.
`ENV` variables are also available during the build, as soon as you introduce them with an `ENV` instruction. 
Here is a `Dockerfile` example, both for default values and without them:

```
ARG some_variable
# or with a hard-coded default:
#ARG some_variable=default_value

RUN echo "Oh dang look at that $some_variable"
```

When building a Docker image from the commandline, you can set `ARG` values using `–build-arg`:

```
$ docker build --build-arg some_variable=a_value
```

Running that command, with the above `Dockerfile`, will result in the following line being printed (among others):

```
Oh dang look at that a_value
```

Here is a basic Dockerfile, using hard-coded `ENV` default values:

```
# no default value
ENV blablabla
# a default value
ENV foo /bar
# or ENV foo=/bar

# ENV values can be used during the build
ADD . $foo
# or ADD . ${foo}
# translates to: ADD . /bar
```

And here is an example of a Dockerfile, using dynamic on-build env values:

```
# expect a build-time variable
ARG A_VARIABLE
# use the value to set the ENV var default
ENV an_env_var=$A_VARIABLE
# if not overridden, that value of an_env_var will be available to your containers!
```

If you use docker-compose you may set it in the file ([link](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#environment)): 
version: '3'

```
services:
  php:
    image: my_php
      environment:
        - MY_NEWRELIC_KEY=keykey
```

**EDIT**:
You can specify a file to read values from. 
The file above is called env_file (name arbitrary) and it’s located in the current directory. You can reference the filename, which is parsed to extract the environment variables to set:

```
$ docker run --env-file=env_file php env
```

With docker-compose.yml files, we just reference a env_file, and `Docker` parses it for the variables to set.

```
version: '3'

services:
  php:
    image: php
      env_file: env_file
```

Comment: I need to pass variable from .env file of Laravel. Did you even read the question?

Comment: I've updated the answer. However - it is just a copy-paste from a doc which I mentioned in the answer.